# Matrix invertiblity proof

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

Let $A$ be an $n × n$ matrix. Prove that either $A$ is invertible or there exists a non-zero matrix $B$ such that $AB = 0$ matrix of size $n×n$.

Comment: A follow-up. Prove that if $A$ is not invertible, then there is a nonzero $B$ with $AB=0$ and $BA=0$.

Comment: Another follow up: http://www.imc-math.org.uk/imc2016/imc2016-day1-questions.pdf

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $AB = 0$ means that for each column $x$ of $B$, $Ax = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Think of linear transformations instead of the matrices.

Suppose $A$ is non-invertible map $V\rightarrow V$, let $W$ be the subspace, let $v_1,\dots,v_k$ be a basis for $W$ and extend it so that $v_1,v_2,\dots, v_n$ is a basis for $V$.

If we define the map $B$ through this basis so that $T(v_i)=0$ if $i\leq k$ and $T(V_i)=v_i$ otherwise we get the desired transform $B$.

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ is non-invertible then $0$ is  eigenvalue of $A$ i.e for some non-zero vector $v$  we have $Av=0v=\mathbf{0}$.

So the matrix $B= [ v \ v \ \dots \ \ v]_{n \times n}$ satisfies $AB=0$.